# find text in XML node using vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript, xml-parsing

I have XML like :

```
<ECSC>
  <SCRIPT>
 <ETXML_LINE_TABTYPE>
                <item>*******************************************************************************.</item>
        <item>* Information.</item>
        <item>********************************************************************************.</item>
        <item>* Script for test case 'TF_FI_FP_FI_0569_MS07_CO_Search_Help_Internal_Orders_vTD0_1_EN.x'</item>
        <item>*</item>
        <item>* For Sub script:</item>
        <item>*  'Test case 3: Choose an Internal Order in One.Fi using external order number while transaction posting (positive case)'.</item>
        <item>*</item>
        <item>* Script is to Display Internal Order using external order number while Transaction Posting 'FB01'</item>
        <item>* GETTAB command is being used to fetch the data from table 'COAS'.</item>
        <item>*</item>
        <item>*</item>
        <item>*     Test data related Information</item>
        <item>*     -----------------------------</item>
        <item>* Default test data present in parameter list has been used while Scripting ( script recording &amp; Performing Checks ).</item>
        <item>*</item>
        <item>* Final execution of result log: 0000037077.</item>
        <item>*</item>
        <item>********************************************************************************.</item>
        <item>* Preparation.</item>
        <item>********************************************************************************.</item>
        <item/>
        <item/>
        <item>********************************************************************************.</item>
        <item>* End Preparation.</item>
        <item>********************************************************************************.</item>
        <item/>
        <item/>
        <item>********************************************************************************.</item>
        <item>* Execution.</item>
        <item>********************************************************************************.</item>
        <item>* To get the 'Table Entries' from table 'COAS'.</item>
        <item>  GETTAB ( COAS , COAS_1 ).</item>
        <item>* To display the value for the field 'External Order No'.</item>
        <item>  LOG ( V_EXTERNAL_ORDER_NO_FRM_TABL ).</item>
        <item/>
        <item>*----------------------Posting(FB01)-------------------------------------------*.</item>
        <item/>
        <item>* This part of Script is to Display Internal Order using external order number while Transaction Posting 'FB01'.</item>
        <item>MESSAGE ( MSG_1 ).</item>

        <item>  GETGUI ( FB01_100_STEP_1 ).</item>

        <item>  SAPGUI ( FB01_100_STEP_2 ).</item>
        <item>* Enter Amount and Tax Code.</item>
        <item>* and, Press F4 help in the Order Field.</item>
        <item>  SAPGUI ( FB01_300_STEP_1 ).</item>
        <item>* In F4 screen, enter the 'External Order Number'</item>
        <item>* pop-up screen is displayed with entries like Order, Description and External Order Number and select 1st order row, press Enter.</item>
        <item>  SAPGUI ( FB01_200_STEP_1 ).</item>
        <item>* To get the values for the field 'Order, Description and External Order No' from F4 help.</item>
        <item>  GETGUI ( FB01_120_STEP_1 ).</item>
        <item>* Press 'Enter' button.</item>
        <item>  SAPGUI ( FB01_120_STEP_3 ).</item>
        <item>* To get the value for the field 'Order' from Main screen.</item>
        <item>  GETGUI ( FB01_300_STEP_2 ).</item>
        <item>* click on 'F3' back button.</item>
        <item>  SAPGUI ( FB01_300_STEP_3 ).</item>
        <item>* click on 'F3' back button.</item>
        <item>  SAPGUI ( FB01_700_STEP_1 ).</item>
        <item>* click 'Yes' button.</item>
        <item>  SAPGUI ( FB01_200_STEP_2 ).</item>
        <item>* click on 'F3' back button.</item>
        <item>  SAPGUI ( FB01_100_STEP_3 ).</item>
        <item>ENDMESSAGE ( E_MSG_1 ).</item>
        <item/>
        <item>* To display the Title Screen.</item>
        <item>  LOG ( V_TITLE_SCREEN ).</item>
        <item>* To display the 'Order' Number from F4 help.</item>
        <item>  LOG ( V_ORDER_NO_FROM_F4 ).</item>
        <item>* To display the 'Description' from F4 help.</item>
        <item>  LOG ( V_DESCRIPTION_FROM_F4).</item>
        <item>* To display the 'External Order no' value from F4 help.</item>
        <item>  LOG ( V_EXTERNAL_ORDER_NO_FROM_F4 ).</item>
        <item>* To display the 'Order' Number from main screen.</item>
        <item>  LOG ( V_ORDER_NO_FRM_MAIN_SCREEN ).</item>
        <item>********************************************************************************.</item>
        <item>* End Execution.</item>
        <item>********************************************************************************.</item>
        <item/>
        <item>********************************************************************************.</item>
        <item>* Check.</item>
        <item>********************************************************************************.</item>
        <item>* To check name of Title screen for transaction FB01.</item>
        <item>  CHEVAR ( V_TITLE_SCREEN = I_TITLE_SCREEN ).</item>
        <item>* To check the value for the field 'External Order No' from F4 help, which should be equal to 'External Order No' from table.</item>
        <item>  CHEVAR ( V_EXTERNAL_ORDER_NO_FRM_TABL = V_EXTERNAL_ORDER_NO_FROM_F4 ).</item>
        <item>* To check the values for the field 'Order' number from Table, which should be equal to 'Order' no from F4 screen and Main screen.</item>
        <item>  CHEVAR ( ( I_ORDER_NUMBER_FROM_TABLE = V_ORDER_NO_FROM_F4 ) AND ( I_ORDER_NUMBER_FROM_TABLE = V_ORDER_NO_FRM_MAIN_SCREEN )).</item>
        <item>********************************************************************************.</item>
        <item>* End Check.</item>
        <item>********************************************************************************.</item>
</ETXML_LINE_TABTYPE>
  </SCRIPT>      
 </ECSC>
```

From above XML file I want to check from "MESSAGE" block to "ENDMESSAGE" block whether this block contain statement like "SAPGUI" is exist or not. If word "SAPGUI" is not exist in above XML MESSAGE block then VBscript should display error.
This is my tried VB Script code :

```
 Dim oFS      : Set oFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Dim sFSpec   : sFSpec   = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("D:\new\Link\xmlsample.xml")
 Dim objMSXML : Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
 objMSXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
 objMSXML.async = False
 objMSXML.load sFSpec
 sapgui=0
 Set oNodeList2 = objMSXML.documentElement.selectNodes("/ECSC/SCRIPT/ETXML_LINE_TABTYPE/item")
 For Each ndItem In oNodeList2
       Dim sItem : sItem = ndItem.text
       If (Left(sItem, 7)="MESSAGE") Then
      If (Left(sItem, 8)="  SAPGUI") Then
        sapgui=sapgui+1
        msgbox("SAPGUI is present")
      else
            if(sapgui = 0) Then
                msgbox("SAPGUI code is not present")
        End if
      End If
  End If
 Next
```

Please help me for this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is 'ECSC' the document element (root)? Or is that a small part of a larger file?

Comment: It looks to me like what you want to do is validate a line-oriented script. Why is this wrapped into XML in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this to check if there's a string `SAPGUI` between `MESSAGE` and `ENDMESSAGE`:

```vbs
Set oNodeList = objMSXML.selectSingleNode("//ETXML_LINE_TABTYPE").selectNodes("//item")

ReDim items(oNodeList.Length - 1)
i = 0
For Each node In oNodeList
  items(i) = node.text
  i = i + 1
Next

txt = Join(items, vbLf)

Set msg = New RegExp
msg.Pattern = "MESSAGE([\s\S]*?)ENDMESSAGE"

For Each m In re.Execute(txt)
  If InStr(m.SubMatches(0), "SAPGUI") > 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Message contains SAPGUI."
  Else
    WScript.Echo "Message does not contain SAPGUI."
  End If
Next
```

Probably not the most elegant way of doing this, but the same can be said about the format of the input data.

Answer (score 0):

You can make better use of XPath to do the matching you want. I used the exact same sample XML you gave and came up with this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim xml : Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
Call xml.SetProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath")
xml.Async = False
Call xml.Load("test.xml")

Dim nl : Set nl = xml.documentElement.selectNodes("//ETXML_LINE_TABTYPE/item[text()='MESSAGE.']/../item[contains(.,'SAPGUI')]")

If nl Is Nothing Or nl.Length < 1 Then
  Call MsgBox("Error", vbCritical, "Error")
End If

WScript.Quit
```

It will give an error if the 'item' node containing the text 'MESSAGE.' does not have any sibling 'item' node containing the text 'SAPGUI'

Comment: yes 'ECSC' is document element root. Thank you the solution which is provided by you is working fine. but It is working for small XML file not for big XML file like I have updated my XML file. And I want to just validate only this block like `<item>MESSAGE</item>` to `<item>ENDMESSAGE</item>` if only this block contains the word like "SAPGUI" then its correct And if This block doen't exist any "SAPGUI" word then VBScript should display Error. Please reply me as soon as possible. Thank You in advance.

Comment: The XPath expression only checks the existence of an `<item>` node containing the string `SAPGUI`, ignoring whether or not it's between `MESSAGE.` and `ENDMESSAGE.`.

Comment: Ah good point. I also agree that its weird this is XML in the first place

Comment: ok friend it means my requirement will not be implemented using vbscript..? its technical limitation of vbscript and XML..? Thanks for your valuable help.

Comment: @user3728765: It's not a technical limitation, it's just a badly chosen format.